# How to import a .css from a library without fully overriding my .scss

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Basically, I want to use the styles that the rsuite library provides because I wanted to use a ranged date picker that it has.
The thing is that, for it to display properly, I need to make an import of the `.css` of the library rsuit.
I have a component with a `.scss` file and an `index.tsx` file where I import the `.scss` one in this way:

```
import './styles.scss';
```

Then, in `styles.scss` I import the library `.css` this way:

```
@use '../../../styles/breakpoints'; //These are other .scss we use.
@use '../../../styles/fonts';
@use '../../../styles/colors';
@import '~rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
```

My problem is that, when I do this, it overrides basically everything. Changing fonts, paddings... and yes, the range date picker now works and shows properly, but I only want it to change, nothing more.

Any way I can fix this? Or any way to select what I want to import from the library `.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scope the imported stylesheet by importing it inside a style rule...

```
#someRandomID{
    @import '~rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
}
```

This will make the whole CSS work only for elements inside element with ID "someRandomID", this way it won't overwrite your styles.

Now you that you have imported the styles and that they do not impact yours, it will also not style the datepicker! The trick here would be to `@extend` with your class. I did not dig into rsuite, so let's say the class for the datepicker is indeed `.datepicker`. This means that it got included as `#someRandomID .datepicker` and we'd like to "alias" this as `.datepicker` only.

You can use `@extend` for this:

```
.datepicket{
    @extend #someRandomID .datepicker;
}
```

You may need to do that for every styles tough, so I'm not sure it's gonna be very helpful. It would also have the very bad drawback of including the whole CSS for absolutely nothing, bloating your css file by huge amounts needlessly.

With all that in mind, I think the best bet for you would be to simply get the source CSS that you need from their github. https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/blob/main/src/DatePicker/styles/index.less

Comment: Hello @Salketer, I tried to import the CSS straight from their .less
Even I saw that you can make an import straight from the DateRangedPicker which is the one I want to use.
But when I try to import inside my index.tsx this way:
```
import 'rsuite/DateRangePicker/styles/index.less';
```
It doesn´t seems to work.
I tried copying it to a new .less file, but seems pointless because then I'll also need to copy all the imports they have.